# Is my lucky bamboo healthy?

Tags: lucky-bamboo

I got a lucky bamboo yesterday but it had some red spots on the leaves and stem. Also one of the stem is turning yellow. The tips of one of the leaf is also yellow. These are red spots not brown. Also the plant is in soil. Please note its winter here with temperature of 30°C high and 18°C low. The rest of the plant look healthy to me with green leaves. Pics attched[image]

[image]